# How can I set focus on my next textbox in another row after saving?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I just wanted to ask you guys if how can I set my cursor to focus on the next text box after saving. I have a table where there is a text box and a save button on each row. All I wanted is when I click the save button it will focus on the next textbox in the next row? thank you in advance for helping me.

Comment: Or at the very least, your HTML code and JS in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this

```
$("#savebuttonId").click(function () {

    $(this).closest("tr").next().find("textarea").focus();
});
```

First you need to find the current parent `tr` using `closest()`, then use `next()` to find the next `tr`. Finally use `find()` to get the child textarea.